How to enforce wso2 apim to check previous password when trying to change password?
We want to add a 'change password policy' that compares the new password with the previous password in WSO2 apim when changing Publisher or Devportal password.

wso2 apim version is 4.4 .
We did not find any way!
We also checked password policies section in wso2 apim documents.
Could you help me?
We prefer not using wso2 identity server.

WSO2 API Manager does not have this feature, as user management-related tasks are not part of the APIM scope. APIM only has basic user-related features. The password history feature is available in WSO2 Identity Server, as outlined in [1]. You will need to configure WSO2 IS with APIM to use these features. You can configure WSO2 IS as an external IDP by following this document [2].
[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/password-mgt/password-policies/#validate-password-history
[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/configuring-identity-server-as-external-idp-using-oidc/
